# psql: How to include comments in \d output

Tags: postgresql, psql

In PostgreSQL it is possible to add comments to table columns. These will appear in the `psql` output from the "extended describe" `\d+` command, however they will not appear in the standard `\d` output.

Is there a psql setting or default that can be tweaked to make these comments appear in `\d` output?

The motivation here is that most people use primarily `\d` for inspecting the schema and I want to make the schema documentation more easily discoverable.

Comment: nice to see a fellow alumni here :-) It is a small world